# Compatible CPU models?

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I have a relatively old computer that I just upgraded the RAM in, and I am thinking of upgrading the CPU. I was wondering if CPU models have to be compatible to your motherboard and whatnot besides having the right socket type, and if so, do you have any CPUs to reccommend. (I would prefer to stay with AMD processors).
My current system specs are:
OS: Windows XP Home Edition (32-bit)
CPU: AMD Athlon XP 2800+ Single-Core. Clock speed 2.08 Ghz
RAM: 2x 1GB DDR333 (PC2700)
Not sure what type the motherboard is, does that matter? (my computer is a HP Pavilion a532x, I haven't changed anything except the RAM, and a new sound card).
Thanks

Comment: No current generation processor will work on your motherboard, and finding anywhere other than ebay that will sell a compatible processor will be very difficult.  Knowing your motherboard model would be important to anyone suggesting an alternative version as they would need to know what socket the processor is and thus if you would be able to fit a dual-core processor.  Trust me, I had that fight a few years ago with an Athlon XP 2400+ and then again a year later when I upgraded my mobo and processor for a Athlon X2 4800+ system, and it's just wasn't worth the money to upgrade it any more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MB manufacturer name: ASUS A7V8X-LA
>
> HP/Compaq name: Kamet2-GL6E
>
> Socket A
>   AMD Athlon/Athlon XP
>   Barton core support
>
> Maximum approved processors:
>
> Athlon XP 3000+ Barton core (2.167 GHz, 333MHz)
>
> Athlon XP 2700+ Thoroughbred core (2.16GHz, 266MHz)

[Information Source](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00063254&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=412538)

Since this is an Asus board manufactured for HP, the processors it can use are limited by the HP bios, if I were to guess I would suspect the Athlon XP 3200+ would work also.

[Athlon XP Barton Processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Athlon_XP_microprocessors#Athlon_XP_.22Barton.22_.28Model_10.2C_130_nm.29)

.

Comment: Watch out for BIOS issues as Moab said - I once tried to upgrade an HP Pavilion with a 3GHz P4 but the BIOS would only clock it at 2.53 GHZ max even though the faster processor was listed as supported by the generic (non-HP customised) Asus board.